# Foreach nested in a while loop with PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach, while-loop

To trim the fat so-to-speak in my script I decided to use 1 PDO prepare to span an array of predefined tables. The PDO executes in a `while` loop and within the `while` loop there is a `foreach` to build the output of each result set.

This is code for a search. The script currently searches 3 tables for results (through the `while` iterations). We will call them tables a, b, and c. For the tested search it finds 2 results in table a, 0 in table b, and 1 in table c.

Though it finds a total of 3 results it only displays 2. One from table 'a' and one from table 'c'. The script is not building the result from the second find in the table 'a'.

I have looked it over until my eyes bleed and searched for maybe something I have wrong, I cant figure it out. Any ideas of what is wrong with this code?

```
// --- Build an array of places to search
$tableArray = array("services", "webPages", "dsiu");
$tableCount = count($tableArray);
$count = "0";
$resCount = "0";

$result = "";
while ($tableCount > $count) {
    // -- Search tables in the array for matches
    $quotedString = $db->quote($searchString);
    $qSQL = "SELECT title, ldesc, SUM(MATCH(title, sdesc, ldesc) AGAINST(:string IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AS score FROM ".$tableArray[$count]." WHERE MATCH (title, sdesc, ldesc) AGAINST (:string IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY score DESC";
    $q = $db->prepare($qSQL);
    $q->execute(array(':string'=>$quotedString));

    // -- keep a count of the results
    $rowCount = $q->rowCount();

    if ($rowCount > 0) {
        $resCount = $resCount + $rowCount;

        // -- build result html
        $html = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($html as $row) {

            // --- Clean the results for display
            $desc = cleanURL($row['ldesc']);
            $desc = str_ireplace($searchString, '<b><font color="green">'.$searchString.'</font></b>', $desc);
            $desc = substr($desc, 0, 300)."...";

            $result .= "<font color='red'><b>".$row['title']."</b></font><br>".$desc."<br><br>";

        }
    }

    $count++;
}
```

Comment: a bit off-topic: Both the field names and the query itself look rather specific <- why are there multiple tables anyway?

Comment: This is for a website. Different elements of the site are separated in the DB. This is to allow the visitors search to check the different elements for a result. Eventually all elements will be incorporated into a site wide search. A user could get results from 'company services provided', the online store, or the 'informational pages' or select specific elements to conduct a search on.

Comment: Are there 2 results for table a in `$html` ?

Comment: "This is to allow the visitors search to check the different elements for a result" - this _could_ be done with an additional (flag) field in the database; _would_ e.g. make it easier to combine search results and some other possible improvements. But anyway, offtopic ;-)

Comment: @dan08 no, I just used a `print_r($html)` There is 1 result for table 'a', table 'b' returns an empty result, table 'c' 1 result. Array ( [0] => Array ( [title] => Printer or MFP Setup [ldesc] => sdfdsf [score] => 2 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [title] => [ldesc] => [score] => ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [title] => How Wifi Works [ldesc] => jkds lf [score] => 2 ) )

Comment: its counting the empty result as a return.

Comment: The I don't get what the problem is? can you edit your question and clarify.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @dan08. I added a `if ($row['score'] != null) {` to the `foreach`. Also discovered that `SUM()` in the query was removing what should have been results.

This is now working with the changes.